# R: plota.format() function

Tags: r, visualization

I was reading this article: [Visualizing Tables with plot.table](http://www.r-bloggers.com/visualizing-tables-with-plot-table/). In it there is a mention of a function `plota.format()`. I tried running that function with my data to see the visualization. But I am getting the following error:

> Error: could not find function "plota.format"*

My question is: Which package does `plota.format()` belong to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like it's an actual package, but you can get it with the following (which I borrowed from the [author's github](https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT)

```
> library(RCurl)
> sit <- getURLContent(
        'https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/raw/master/sit.gz',
        binary = TRUE, followlocation = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
> con <- gzcon(rawConnection(sit, 'rb'))
> source(con)
> close(con)
> plota.format
```

The source code looks like it's not formatted as source code normally is, so I'm guessing this might be the only way.  If you take a look at `ls()` now, you'll see you've got all the functions in the package so you might want to save them.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it to work from  the link provided by voidHead

Comment: @Richard "not formatted as source code normally is" - very diplomatic!

Comment: @voidHead - Haha, I didn't want to offend anyone with "looks terrible".  You never know when the package authors might be lurking about.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be in the package Systematic Investor Toolbox, described in the link you posted. You can view it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT).

Comment: @EsBee No problem, easily overlooked.